# JAVA: multiple files download at the same time?

Tags: java, struts, download

Is there any methods for downloading multiple files at the same time? That is, after select multiple files, click the download button, and choose the destination directory, the files selected will be downloaded at the same time.
i googled it and not find any solutions, can anybody know? im using struts1 and spring2.

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of the normal file download model supported by web browsers.  You might be able to do this with some client-side Javascript.  However, I suspect it is not possible, since Javascript driven upload of multiple files would probably entail breaking Javascript's security sandbox.

Comment: ur right. Even if the security was left out of account, client-side javascript cannot hold a big file. A file of 10M will make it no-response.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. You can download a zip though.

Comment: but my customer does not like that.
ps. windows can unzip the zip achive automaticly without any unzip tools?